# Solve for $x$ where $\sin(x)^{\cos(x)}$= $2$

Tags: trigonometry, contest-math, graphing-functions

I found this question in a mathematics book (some kind of challenge questions book). I was just trying to solve this question for fun. At the moment I am a bit confused. So by now, I have tried two things 1st of all is to sub $cos(x)$ as

$\frac{1}{\pm \sqrt{1+\tan^2(x)}}$
and
$\pm \sqrt{\sin^2(x)-1}$.

However, I haven't made any progress. I graphed both equation son desmos and [Graph of both sides of the equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/la3wn.png). I also got this solution from a math computation website [solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmaQh.png).
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @Vasili, your hint seems to suggest that a solution does not exist. The function $f(x) = \sin(x)^{\cos(x)}$ is continuous on $[0,\pi)$, it is $0$ at $x=0$ and $\lim_{x \to \pi^-} f(x) = +\infty$, so a solution does exist.

Comment: @Gibbs: You are right, as cosine can be negative. My bad.

Comment: For starters, if $x$ is a solution then so is $x+2k\pi$ for any integer $k$, and so it suffices to find all solutions in the interval $[0,2\pi)$. Because $|\sin(x)|\leq1$ you must have $\cos(x)<0$, and $\sin(x)>0$, which means that $x\in[\tfrac{\pi}{2},\pi)$.

Comment: Also note that the solution from the 'math computation website' can easily be simplified a lot; you have
$$\frac{1-\tan\tfrac x2}{1+\tan\tfrac x2}=\cos x.$$

Comment: Solution does exist: answer is about $x=2.665+2\pi n$. $\sin(x)=1$ won't satisfy equation, so $\sin(x)<1$. Let $\sin(x)=2^t$, $t<0$. Then $2^{t\cos(x)}=2$, $\cos(x)=\frac1t < 0$. Then $\cos(x)=-\sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)} \Rightarrow \frac1t+\sqrt{1-2^{2t}}=0$. This equation has no closed-form solution, but plotting can help to find its root.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha does not give the solution but the numerical result

Answer (score 1):

**First approach**

Plotting or by inspection, the first solution is close to $\frac {5  \pi}6$.

Now, consider
$$f(x)=\cos(x)\log(\sin(x))-\log(2)$$ and expand as a Taylor series
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{3}-2\right) \log (2)+\frac{1}{2} \left(x-\frac{5 \pi
   }{6}\right) (3+\log (2))-$$ $$\frac{1}{4} \left(x-\frac{5 \pi }{6}\right)^2
   \left(\sqrt{3} (\log (2)-6)\right)+\left(x-\frac{5 \pi }{6}\right)^3
   \left(\frac{9}{4}-\frac{\log (2)}{12}\right)+$$ $$O\left(\left(x-\frac{5 \pi
   }{6}\right)^4\right)$$

Using series reversion
$$x=\frac{5 \pi }{6}+t+\frac{\sqrt{3}  (\log (2)-6)}{6+\log (4)}t^2+\frac{ (243+\log
   (4) (\log (32)-66))}{6 (3+\log (2))^2}t^3+O\left(t^{4}\right)$$ where $t=\frac{2 f(x)+(2-\sqrt{3}) \log (2)}{3+\log (2)}$.

Since you want $f(x)=0$, then the *approximation*
$x \approx 2.6653795$ while the "exact" solution, given by Newton method, is
$x=2.6653571$

**Second approach**

Using the tangent half-angle substitution $x=2\tan^{-1}(t)$, you need to find the zero of function
$$g(t)=\left(\frac{2 t}{t^2+1}\right)^{\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}}-2$$ Plotting, the solution is close to $t=4$ and the function is very close to linearity. Using Newton method, the iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 4.000000000 \\
 1 & 4.120370127 \\
 2 & 4.119928024 \\
 3 & 4.119928018
\end{array}
\right)$$ Back to $x$, $x=2.6653571$.

**Third approach**

The derivative of $f(x)$ cancels at $x=\frac \pi 2$ and the second derivative test shows that it is a local minimum. Expand as a series
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2} \left(x-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^3+\frac{1}{80} \left(x-\frac{\pi
   }{2}\right)^7+O\left(\left(x-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^9\right)-\log(2)$$ Using the first term only, a first estimate
$$x_0=\frac{\pi }{2}+\sqrt[3]{2 \log (2)}=2.68582$$ Plug this is the second term
$$0=\frac{1}{2} \left(x-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^3+\frac{1}{80} \log ^{\frac{7}{3}}(4)-\log(2)$$
$$x_1=\frac{\pi }{2}+\sqrt[3]{\log (4)-\frac{1}{40} \log ^{\frac{7}{3}}(4)}=2.67127$$

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$\sin(x)^{\cos(x)} = 2$$

We'd want to take $\cos(x) = \sqrt{1 - [\sin(x)]^2}$, but the solutions can only happen when $\cos(x)$ is negative, because there is no other way to get a value larger than 1, given that $\sin(x)$ is never larger than 1. Hence we must negate the square root, giving

$$\sin(x)^{-\sqrt{1 - [\sin(x)]^2}} = 2$$

Now take $u = \sin(x)$, so

$$u^{-\sqrt{1 - u^2}} = 2$$

Taking the log of both sides gives

$$-\sqrt{1 - u^2} \ln(u) = \ln(2)$$

Take $u = e^{v/2}$,

$$-\sqrt{1 - e^v} \frac{v}{2} = \ln(2)$$

so

$$-\sqrt{1 - e^v} v = 2 \ln(2)$$
$$(1 - e^v) v^2 = 4 [\ln(2)]^2$$
$$1 - e^v = 4 \frac{[\ln(2)]^2}{v^2}$$
$$e^v = 1 - 4 \frac{[\ln(2)]^2}{v^2} = \frac{v^2 - 4 [\ln(2)]^2}{v^2}$$

which can be factored and rearranged to

$$e^v = \frac{(v - 2 \ln(2))(v + 2 \ln(2))}{v^2}$$

But, I think, this is either as far or not as far as it gets when it comes to solving the equation, and the reason I say this is this is a special case of general equations of the type

$$e^v = \frac{(v - a)(v - b)}{(v - c)(v - d)}$$

which have been examined before:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.3999.pdf

as a *generalization* of the Lambert W-function. Thus, there is likely to be no solution either using elementary functions or even the standard Lambert W-function as an addition. In Mezo's notation, though, we could say

$$v = W\left(\begin{matrix}0 && 0\\2 \ln(2) && -2 \ln(2)\end{matrix}; 1\right)$$

hence

$$x = \sin\left(e^{\frac{1}{2} W\left(\begin{matrix}0 && 0\\2 \ln(2) && -2 \ln(2)\end{matrix}; 1\right)}\right).$$

But I suspect hardly any are familiar or have a good intuition for the behavior of Mezo's generalized Lambert functions, so this may not be helpful or insightful. Generally speaking these equations though will not have "nice" answers to them anyways.

Comment: There is also a series expansion for the solution, in the paper, which may be more usable than the ‘closed form’